# Retrieving value of displayed div using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I've 2  elements. Each one have same class name. For example,

```
<div class="test">Value1</div>
<div class="test" style="display:none;">Value2</div>
```

In the above example I want to get the displayed div's value. ie, Value1.

How can I do this using jquery? Kindly help me

Comment: `$('.test:visible').text()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($(".test:visible").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Value1</div>
<div class="test" style="display:none;">Value2</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check `visibility` using jquery [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```js
var val = $(".test:visible").text();
console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Value1</div>
<div class="test" style="display:none;">Value2</div>
```